# Binding a GridView, what's missing?

Tags: vb.net, xaml, gridview, binding, windows-8

(Windows 8) I'm trying to get my GridView to bind to some grouped objects that are loaded upon navigation to the page. Basically what I want is to display these loaded objects while the others are still loading.

The following code shows the grid only shows the items after all of them have been loaded:

```
Dim myItems As New ObservableCollection(Of SearchResultItem)
Dim group As New SearchResultGroup With {.Title = "Title"}
group.Items = myItems
' Loading code here
DefaultViewModel("Groups") = New ObservableCollection(Of SearchResultGroup)({group})
```

However, the following doesn't show anything at all:

```
Dim myItems As New ObservableCollection(Of SearchResultItem)
Dim group As New SearchResultGroup With {.Title = "Title"}
group.Items = myItems
DefaultViewModel("Groups") = New ObservableCollection(Of SearchResultGroup)({group})
' Loading code here
```

(This is under the async LoadState function)

Here is the code for the page:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage DataContext={Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}} ... >
    <Page.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource
            x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
            Source="{Binding Groups}"
            IsSourceGrouped="true"
            ItemsPath="Items"/>
        ...
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
        ....
        <GridView
            x:Name="itemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Padding="116,137,40,46"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource},Mode=TwoWay}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResultTemplate}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsSwipeEnabled="false"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True">
            ...
```

Here are the custom item and group classes I used:

```
Public Class SearchResultGroup
    Inherits BindableBase

    Public Sub New() ...
    Private _Title As String
    Property Title As String ...
    Private _Items As ObservableCollection(Of SearchResultItem)
    Property Items As ObservableCollection(Of SearchResultItem) ...
End Class

Public Class SearchResultItem
    Inherits BindableBase

    Private _Title As String       
    Property Title As String ...
    Private _Title2 As String
    Property Title2 As String ...
    Private _Subtitle As String
    Property Subtitle As String
End Class
```

(Just cutting out some unnecessary code here... will edit as needed)

Comment: Are you adding and removing groups or group items?  If group items then check to see if groups implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I'm adding both groups and group items... (I'm mostly just adding, but being able to remove items will be useful in the future) And the group class SearchResultGroup inherits from BindableBase, which implements INotifyPropertyChanged.